# Lucene: Find documents that match a query and the documents that share a field value with the matched documents

Tags: java, lucene

I am currently playing around with lucene to find out if it might suit the requirements for a use case that can be outlined as follows:

- unordered incoming messages in a relatively high frequency (4 million/day) are stored inside lucene as documents as they arrive
- the messages are linked together (chained) with a specific field value
- when querying for messages the whole chain should be returned

**Example of arriving messages:**

Format: (`{<fieldName_1>:<fieldValue_1>; <fieldnName_n>:<fieldnValue_N>; ...}`)

```
1: {chain:1; attr1:a; attr2:b; ...}
2: {chain:2; attr1:c; attr2:d; ...}
3: {chain:1; attr3:e; attr4:f; ...}
4: {chain:2; attr3:g; attr4:h; ...}
...
```

So in the above example we have 4 messages belonging to two chains.

**My question based on the example is:**

What would be the best (performance wise) strategy for being able to perform queries like the following:

- `attr1==a AND attr2==b` and get message 1 and 3 returned or to query for
- `attr1==a OR attr2==d` and to get all 4 messages returned

Can I already do something like this when adding the messages to lucene?

**What I tried so far:**

- I tried merging the message attributes in a single document: Query the index for the chain of the incoming message, creating a new message with merged attributes of *the query result and the new message*, adding the merged message as new document and finally deleting the original document. This way the queries would be very easy because the whole chain is in one document but unfortunately that turned out as a performance nightmare for writing.

Best regards